# Elastic search to have mapped column value as the ID using spark submit

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, apache-spark, apache-kafka

My spark submit pulls data from kafka and puts to elastic Search, i am using the below snippet to run the RDD.
facts.foreachRDD(fact -> {
        JavaEsSpark.saveJsonToEs(fact, esIndex + "/" + esType);

Please help me find a way so that my Fact (Elastic Search Mapping) column event_id is the "_id" of the Elastic Search Document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
facts.foreachRDD(fact -> { JavaEsSpark.saveJsonToEs(fact, esIndex

 + "/" + esType, ImmutableMap.of("es.mapping.id", "your_column_name"));});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `es.mapping.id` configuration to achieve that. Set your sparkConf with this configuration as follows:

```
sparkConf.set("es.mapping.id","<field_name_to_be_used_as_id>") //in your case it is "event_id"
```

You can find documentation for this config [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html#cfg-mapping)

Hope this helps!